# Get top N rows from table on the basis of group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have Customer_Record table with following columns

```
customer_id | item_id | item_count
1            2           10
1            3           9
1            4           2
1            5           2
2            2           5
2            4           1
2            8           2
4            1           2            
4            5           3
4            8           7
```

Now i want to get top 2 items (items_id) of each customer on the basis of item_count.
Please help me to figure out this .

Result like:-

```
customer_id | item_id | item_count
1            2           10
1            3           9
2            2           5
2            4           1
4            1           2
```

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the requirement ?!?

Comment: ...and what about ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql you can use rank query to get top results per group

```
SELECT t.customer_id,
t.item_id,
t.item_count
FROM (
SELECT t.*,
@rank:= CASE WHEN @group = t.customer_id THEN @rank +1 ELSE 1 END rank ,
@group:= t.customer_id 
 FROM
t
JOIN (SELECT @group:='',@rank:='') t1
ORDER BY t.customer_id ,item_count  DESC
) t WHERE t.rank <=2
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42839/3)